# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I am using springboot controller as back end and Angular 9 as front end. I got this error when I try to call a login function with some html header enclosed. I tried to install some CORS plugin for chrome, but I still get this error. Would anyone spot abnormal parts in my code? I have no clue where to start with.

Spring Controller:

```
@RestController 
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/validateLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public User validateLogin(@RequestHeader("username") String username, @RequestHeader("password") String password) {

        User user = new User();
        return user;
    }
```

Angular call:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) {}

  authenticate(username, password) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.httpClient.get<User>('http://localhost:8080/api/validateLogin',{headers}).pipe(
     map(
       userData => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('username',username);
        return userData;
       }
     )
   )
  }
```

Comment: Can u try keeping only `@CrossOrigin` annotation, removing the localhost address.

Comment: I have tried that but it yields the same error message

Comment: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the" … on the what?

Comment: Is the request successful if you try it from a client like postman or insomnia ?

Comment: Confirm if you have specified the correct endpoint in your Angular front end.